# How to use properly use a search function and json parser?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

In my view I have

```
<%= form_tag searches_path, method: 'get', do %>
  <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and in my controller I have

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    raw_result = params[:search]
    result = raw_result.gsub(/\s+/, "+")
    movie_details = HTTParty.get("http://imdbapi.org/?title="+result+"&type=json")
    @searches = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(movie_details)


  end
end
```

When I visit the view I get a undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass.  I'm guessing because the form hasn't been submitted.  Am I implementing the json parser correctly?

Comment: On first access, where do you think your params[:search] get set?

Comment: when I click the submit button it gets set, so do I need to have a default value for raw_result? or an if raw_result.exists?

Comment: Yes, on your first access, `params[:search]` is `nil` so you could write `raw_result = params[:search] || "default value"`

Comment: that'll do it!  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
raw_result = params[:search] || "default value"
```